# XSS when using merge field in JavaScript context - bad sanitization : escaping merge field for only HTML entities

Tags: visualforce, javascript, xss

I have a VisualForce page in which there's a `<apex:outputText>` with attribute `escape="false"`.
The good part is that merge field used for this tag is escaped for HTML entities using `escapeHtml4()` in the page's controller.
This is the VF page

```
    <apex:page controller="ContactsController">
    <apex:repeat value="{!Contacts}" var="con">
        <div onclick="foo('{!con.Name}');">
            <apex:outputText value="{!con.Name}" escape="false"/>
            <apex:outputText value="{!con.Email}" />
        </div>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

and in controller the Name merge field is escaped for HTML.

```
public with sharing class ContactsController {
public List<ContactDetails> Contacts {get; set;}
public ContactsController() {
    List<Contact> contactList= [SELECT Id, Name, Email
                FROM Contact
                LIMIT 100];
    Contacts = new List<ContactDetails>();
    for(Contact con: contactList) {
        Contacts.add(new ContactDetails(con));
    }
}

public class ContactDetails {
    String Name;
    String Email;
    
    public ContactDetails(Contact record){
        this.Name = record.Name;
        this.Email = record.Email;
    }
    // escape for HTML
    public String getName() {
        return Name.escapeHtml4();
    }
    
    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }
}
```

}

In the page you can see there's a surrounding `<div>` element which has a click event handler named `foo` and the merge field is passed to it.
I am unbale to craft a payload to be executed in this JavaScript context as both single quote character and double quote character are escaped . The OWASP cheatsheet series [here](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#why-cant-i-just-html-entity-encode-untrusted-data) states

> But HTML entity encoding doesn't work if you're putting untrusted data inside a  tag anywhere, or an event handler attribute like onmouseover, or inside CSS, or in a URL. So even if you use an HTML entity encoding method everywhere, you are still most likely vulnerable to XSS.

Answers will be much appreciated. Thanks!